# Versioning Server Advice: SVN, TFS, Etc

Tags: svn, versioning

I have a small team of unusually unreliable people and am trying to setup the foundation to keep any progress intact. I am familiar with Team Foundation Server and I like the basic function of checking out/in a single file to work on and locking it. However, for this team, I'll need to operate the server application on a shared hosting Linux server.

I managed to get GIT installed, but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.  Does anyone know of a different version control system to perform these basic file locking functions without maintaining multiple repos?

Comment: If you really need locking (which is rare), a distributed system like Git will not be useful, indeed.

Comment: If they are that unreliable, perhaps some housecleaning is in order.

Comment: This development team is young, both in age and as a whole. There is real potential, but they need to be guided slowly to where they need to be. So i'm not comfortable letting them go at this stage.  But thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Luke heh, understandable.  Although, I wouldn't equate "inexperienced" with "unreliable" =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most new version control systems shy away from pessimistic locking, Microsoft products usually implement it (VSS/TFS).  It is possible to implement it in SVN but as some of the comments state it is usually preferable to use optimistic locking.

With pessimistic locking 1 dev can work on a file at any time, 'locking' it from others.  This removes the potential for any merging of files that have been altered by >1 dev.

With optimistic locking > 1 dev can edit a file at any time, the only 'drawback' for this is that your developers may need to merge.  Having used both I would go for optimistic locking every time, pessimistic just causes a headache.

I would recommend trying to solve the issues that make you want to use pessimistic locking rather than using it as a bandage to try to get your unreliable developers to work right. You never know, allow them some freedom and they might surprise you!

Comment: Thank you, that is a very good description.  That said, I think I'll follow your advice and take a optimistic locking route (some adjustment time will be needed of course).  Is GIT a good system to stay with in this instance?

Comment: I don't have much personal experience in GIT (unfortunately!) but I've always heard glowing reviews.